# how to update git bare repository on server using ssh from local development machine?

Tags: git, ssh, google-cloud-platform, repository, google-compute-engine

I am trying to setup a git repositories for frequently updating from my local git repo to my server on google compute engine.

Currently I am able to connect to google compute engine vm using putty from windows.

Here are procedure I followed.

1. Created a git repository on my local windows development machine.
2. created a bare repository on remote vm.
3. created an user git on remote vm server.
4. copied the ssh key used for putty to git user `.ssh/authorized_keys`
5. added the git remote to my local git repository

   ```
   git remote add origin https://my_serv_ip/path_to_git_repository
   ```

But when I try to git push, I get the error
fatal: repository 'https://my_serv_ip/path_to_git_repository' not found

Any suggestion how to resolve this?

Comment: "created a bare repository on remote vm.. do you have git server installed there? if not you will need gitosis as well

Comment: @CodeWizard I have installed git. do i need to install something git server?

Comment: Of course, unless you are using the file protocol... I'll write a full answer fo you how to so it.,

Comment: You don't need to install a git server if you want to access with ssh.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access the repository using ssh, but you're indicating the https protocol with your uri. Try:

```
git remote add origin git@my_serv_ip:/path_to_git_repository
```

If your git repository is inside the 'git' user's $HOME directory, you can use a local path, e.g:

```
git remote add origin git@my_serv_ip:git_repo.git
```

if your username on my_serv_ip is not *git*, you might need to be more explicit:

```
git remote add origin ssh://username@my_serv_ip:git_repo.git
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the ssh keys. He can't access the repo yet, once he can access it he will have to update the remote URL

Comment: Why do you think he can't access the repo? He has ssh access, but has not described setting up the kind of HTTP server that would be necessary.

Comment: Read the comments under the questions, he mentioned that he did not install Git Server ....... only local git......

Comment: He doesn't need a git server if he has ssh access and local git. At least I never have.

Comment: @SilasCoker I used the command "git ls-remote https://git@serv_ip/path-to-git-repo" at server but getting fatal: repo not found

Comment: @SurjyaNarayanaPadhi Sorry, I missed that you need a colon between the server name and the path, so: git@serv_ip:/path-to-git-repo . I will edit my answer.

Comment: @SilasCoker i changed according to this, but getting error - Permission denied (publickey). On my server /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys has permission 755, owner-username and group username. Is it right setting?

Comment: No, it should only be readable and writeable by you. Use permission 600. Make sure your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file allows public key authentication as well.

Comment: @SilasCoker  in sshd_config file set "PubkeyAuthentication yes". restarted ssh service, but still the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185298/discussion-between-silas-coker-and-surjya-narayana-padhi).

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments, you have installed git but you haven't install git server or Gitosis on your remote machine.

A full doc can be found here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

#### How to install Gitosis?

Follow these steps on how to install it here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Gitosis

The Gitosis will also guide you on how to install ssh on your server and once its installed update your remote url to use ssh

Comment: gitosis is required only for multiple ssh-key management or its mandatory? I can manage only setting up git server? I am having only one user for now.

Comment: If you are the only user simply switch to ssh `git remote add origin git@<ip>/<repo.git>`